# HomeController was not found on this server

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a problem in 4 laravel already a few days ago and still can not understand. When I run the route directly so -> Route :: get ('/', 'HomeController@getIndex'); access it normally, but when I do it via redirect me back that the file was not found. Below is my code.

**my route:**

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return Redirect::to('HomeController');
});
```

**my controller:**

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {
    public function getIndex()
    {
        return View::make('home.hello');
    }
}
```

**my view:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    testing
</body>
</html>
```

**error:**

```
The requested URL /HomeController was not found on this server.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Redirect::to('HomeController');` redirects to a URL, not a controller.

Use `Redirect::action('HomeController@index');` to redirect to a specific controller action.

But anyway, your routes do not make sense. routing `/` to redirect to `HomeController` makes little sense, especially when (it seems) you have no route leading to `HomeController`.

A better way is to BIND the `/` route to your `HomeController`:

`Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getIndex');`

Docs:

- Routing: http://laravel.com/docs/routing
- Controllers: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers
- Redirects: http://laravel.com/docs/responses#redirects

Comment: Hello Alex, I understand perfectly what you mean. I did so having seen several videos on the web and found it to be the correct way, but the videos were about laravel 3, I believe that many things have changed. In the case of my action be index, even action I should pass it along the route? Or you could do it this way? `Route::get('/', 'HomeController');` Thank you for now, even more.

Comment: You can't route to a controller (which action would it execute?). You have to route to a controller+action. `Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getIndex');` works.